# Apache Spark byte size per avro record

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, avro

I have several hundreds of gb's worth of Avro files, each file containing thousands of records pertaining to a mobile application and its usage. One of the keys in the schema is the app version ID, and I need to return the byte size of each record grouped by the version ID. If the schema is set up something like this...

```
 root
 |-- useId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- useTime: double (nullable = true)
 |-- appVersion: string (nullable = true)
 |-- useDetails: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- type: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- something: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- somethingElse: double (nullable = true)
 .
 .
 .
```

...then I want to essentially do something like `select appVersion, sum(bytesPerRecord) from df group by appVersion` in order to gauge the payload sizes (or char count, even) per released version of the app. I haven't found any off-the-shelf solutions for this, and I am not a spark savant either. Is this possible?

Comment: Hi @kemi yes it is possible. Just it give it a try and it should be quite easy. Actually you can even use your query as it is through Spark SqlContext. First load the parquet file from the relevant directory and then try to execute your query

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm not understanding. That query won't work because I made up "bytesPerRecord" to make a point. I also haven't found it easy, so a more specific example would be awesome. Thanks!